# How to keep values over a percentile based on a condition on another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, quantile

Please read this question carefully, considering all aspects, before marking it as duplicate. I also had a stack account but seem to have forgotten on which email, thus a brand new one!

I have a `df` with multiple columns and millions (literally) rows. Here's an example so I can be more specific about my question without revealing sensitive data:

```
a     b     c     d   ...   AAA      BBB   

---   ---  ---   ---  ...   hf4r     192
---   ---  ---   ---  ...   h23g     103
---   ---  ---   ---  ...   9fyd      7
---   ---  ---   ---  ...   hf4r     121
---   ---  ---   ---  ...   hf4r      32
---   ---  ---   ---  ...   h23g      12
...............             ............
```

I want to only keep those rows whose `BBB` value is larger than or equal to the 80th percentile of `BBB`s for their specific `AAA`; for all `AAA`.

I work with pandas. I tried in-line `for`s and `.query`s and just regular calls, but I must be doing something wrong because each time my compiler doesn't like one thing or the other. Will appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need `transform` with `quantile`

```
df[df.BBB>=df.groupby('AAA').BBB.transform('quantile',0.8)]
```

Comment: I like your solution but just note that pandas did raise a Memory Error if I used it over a 100.000.000 elements dataframe.

Comment: Would this do what I want even if the first half of the code doesn't specify the `AAA` ?

Comment: I want "rows whose BBB value is >= the 80th percentile of BBBs **for their specific AAA**" ?! @Wen

Comment: I literally just copied what I had asked in the first place. Your written code compares a general `BBB`. its `AAA` is not specified. Idk how else to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this, even though I upvoted Wen's answer because I didn't know that transform could do this. :)

```
df.loc[df.BBB >= df.describe(percentiles = [.8]).iloc[5]['BBB']]
```

Full code :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'AAA' : ['hf4r', 'hf4r', 'hf4r', 'hf4r', 'hf4r', 'hf4r'],
    'BBB' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
selected_values = df.loc[df.BBB >= df.describe(percentiles = [.8]).iloc[5]['BBB']]
print(df)
print(selected_values)

#     AAA  BBB
# 0  hf4r    1
# 1  hf4r    2
# 2  hf4r    3
# 3  hf4r    4
# 4  hf4r    5
# 5  hf4r    6

#     AAA  BBB
# 4  hf4r    5
# 5  hf4r    6
```

Comment: You only have one `AAA` . It's immeasurably easier that way. I have about ~3K various `AAA` values and I wanna do this for all `AAA`s and only keep their top percentile rows

Comment: That lacks of some groupby() If I have time tomorrow, I'll update and let you know ;)